# How to integrate rsyslog, AWS ELB & Flume

Tags: amazon-web-services, flume, amazon-elb, rsyslog

I have been using a php script to write logs to rsyslog and then rsyslog send messages directly to flume(syslogtcp source) on a tcp port.

Now as I am moving to AWS I want to introduce an ELB(Elastic Load Balancer) layer between rsyslog & flume nodes. So I added an  ELB with tcp port forwarding. It seems like the ELB is getting the events from rsyslog but it is not forwarding it to flume . My flume source is a syslog tcp source which uses the same port on which the load balancer forwards the events.

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: can you share your flume configuration as well.

Comment: this is working now. All I had to do was provide the IP Address of ELB(tcp type) in rsyslog forwarding conf and then provide three IP addresses of the flume agents to ELB to send data in a load balanced manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working now. All I had to do was provide the IP Address of ELB(tcp type) in rsyslog forwarding conf and then provide three IP addresses of the flume agents to ELB to send data in a load balanced manner.